# Avoiding using Option.Value

Tags: f#, idioms

I have a type like this:

```
type TaskRow =
    {
        RowIndex : int
        TaskId : string
        Task : Task option
    }
```

A function returns a list of these records to be processed further. Some of the functions doing that processing are only relevant for `TaskRow` items where `Task` is `Some`. I'm wondering what the best way is to go about that.

The naive way would be doing

```
let taskRowsWithTasks = taskRows |> Seq.filter (fun row -> Option.isSome row.Task)
```

and passing that to those functions, simply assuming that `Task` will never be `None` and using `Task.Value`, risking an NRE if I don't pass in that one special list. That is exactly what the current C# code does but seems rather unidiomatic for F#. I shouldn't be 'assuming' things but rather let the compiler tell me what will work.

More 'functional' would be to pattern match every time the value is relevant and then do/return nothing (and use `choose` or the like) for `None`, but that seems repetitive and wasteful as the same work would be done multiple times.

Another thought was introducing a second, slightly different type:

```
type TaskRowWithTask =
    {
        RowIndex : int
        TaskId : string
        Task : Task
    }
```

The original list would then be filtered into a 'sublist' of this type one to be used where appropriate. I guess that would be okay from a functional perspective, but I wonder whether there's a nicer, idiomatic way without resorting to this kind of 'helper type'.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's quite a bit of value knowing that the tasks have already been filtered, so having two different types can be helpful. Instead of defining two different types (which, in F#, isn't that big a deal, though), you could also consider defining a generic `Row` type:

```
type Row<'a> = {
    RowIndex : int
    TaskId : string
    Item : 'a }
```

This enables you to define a projection like this:

```
let project = function
    | { RowIndex = ridx; TaskId = tid; Item = Some t } ->
        Some { RowIndex = ridx; TaskId = tid; Item = t }
    | _ -> None

let taskRowsWithTasks =
    taskRows
    |> Seq.map project
    |> Seq.choose id
```

If the initial `taskRows` value has the type `seq<Row<Task option>>`, then the resulting `taskRowsWithTasks` sequence has the type `seq<Row<Task>>`.

Comment: Why not `Seq.choose project` instead of `map` + `choose id`?

Comment: Yes, indeed, why not? Because I didn't think of it, that's why, but obviously, it's simpler :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you, the more "pure functional" way is to repeat the pattern match, I mean use a function with `Seq.choose` that does the filtering, instead of saving it to another structure.

```
let tasks = Seq.choose (fun {Task = t} -> t) taskRows
```

The problem is performance as it would be calculated many times, but you can use `Seq.cache` so behind the scenes it's saved into an intermediate structure, while keeping your code more "pure functional" looking.